# Filling in empty elements on a vector from another vector by position [R]

Tags: r

If I have a vector like this with empty elements:

```r
vec_empty_element <- c("z", "a", "", "")
```

Then I have another vector like this which will always be the same length:

```r
needed_names <-  c("x + y", "x/2", "y", "x")
```

How do I replace the empty element in `vec_empty_element` with a value from `needed_names` that is in the same position?

This is what I wanted to end up with:

```r
desired_vec <- c("z", "a", "y", "x")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert the blank (`""` to `NA` and then `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(na_if(vec_empty_element, ""), needed_names)
[1] "z" "a" "y" "x"
```

---

or in `base R` with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(nzchar(vec_empty_element), vec_empty_element, needed_names)
[1] "z" "a" "y" "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `nzchar`:

```r
vec_empty_element <- c("z", "a", "", "")
needed_names <-  c("x + y", "x/2", "y", "x")

vec_empty_element[!nzchar(vec_empty_element)] <- needed_names[!nzchar(vec_empty_element)]
# [1] "z" "a" "y" "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple index:

```
vec_empty_element[vec_empty_element == ""] <- needed_names[vec_empty_element == ""]

#[1] "z" "a" "y" "x"
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
vec_empty_element <- ifelse(vec_empty_element == "", needed_names, vec_empty_element)
```